# API changed error during AOSP build. How to fix?

Tags: java-8, android-5.0-lollipop, android-source, build-error, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Im trying to build AOSP(lollipop) using openjdk 1.8 and during make im getting the following errors.

```
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:24965: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Audio.Genres()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:24976: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:24989: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Audio.Media()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25002: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Audio.Playlists()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25012: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25035: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Files()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25053: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Images()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25070: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Images.Media()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25085: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25121: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Video()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25127: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Video.Media()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25136: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25246: error 9: Removed public constructor Settings.Global()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25302: error 9: Removed public constructor Settings.NameValueTable()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25310: error 9: Removed public constructor Settings.Secure()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25394: error 9: Removed public constructor Settings.SettingNotFoundException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25398: error 9: Removed public constructor Settings.System()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25537: error 9: Removed public constructor SyncStateContract.Constants()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25542: error 9: Removed public constructor SyncStateContract.Helpers()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:25838: error 9: Removed public constructor UserDictionary.Words()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26135: error 9: Removed public constructor Element.Builder(RenderScript)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26461: error 9: Removed public constructor RenderScript.RSErrorHandler()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26468: error 9: Removed public constructor RenderScript.RSMessageHandler()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26493: error 9: Removed public constructor Sampler.Builder(RenderScript)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26543: error 9: Removed public constructor Script.FieldBase()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26561: error 9: Removed public constructor Script.LaunchOptions()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26587: error 9: Removed public constructor ScriptGroup.Builder(RenderScript)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26778: error 9: Removed public constructor Type.Builder(RenderScript,Element)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26885: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(Context)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26903: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStoreParameter.Builder(Context)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26935: error 9: Removed public constructor CarrierMessagingService.SendMmsResult(int,byte)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26941: error 9: Removed public constructor CarrierMessagingService.SendMultipartSmsResult(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:26947: error 9: Removed public constructor CarrierMessagingService.SendSmsResult(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27027: error 9: Removed public constructor MediaBrowserService.BrowserRoot(String,Bundle)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27071: error 9: Removed public constructor NotificationListenerService.Ranking()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27128: error 9: Removed public constructor SpellCheckerService.Session()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27161: error 9: Removed public constructor AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.Callback()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27219: error 9: Removed public constructor WallpaperService.Engine()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27438: error 9: Removed public constructor TextToSpeech.Engine()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:27472: error 9: Removed public constructor TextToSpeech.EngineInfo()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:28648: error 9: Removed public constructor SubscriptionManager.OnSubscriptionsChangedListener()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:28844: error 9: Removed public constructor SmsMessage.SubmitPdu()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29442: error 9: Removed public constructor TestSuiteBuilder.FailedToCreateTests(Exception)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29521: error 9: Removed public constructor BidiFormatter.Builder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29522: error 9: Removed public constructor BidiFormatter.Builder(boolean)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29523: error 9: Removed public constructor BidiFormatter.Builder(Locale)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29553: error 9: Removed public constructor BoringLayout.Metrics()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29597: error 9: Removed public constructor Editable.Factory()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29626: error 9: Removed public constructor InputFilter.AllCaps()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29631: error 9: Removed public constructor InputFilter.LengthFilter(int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29751: error 9: Removed public constructor LoginFilter.PasswordFilterGMail()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29752: error 9: Removed public constructor LoginFilter.PasswordFilterGMail(boolean)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29757: error 9: Removed public constructor LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGMail()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29758: error 9: Removed public constructor LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGMail(boolean)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29763: error 9: Removed public constructor LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGeneric()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29764: error 9: Removed public constructor LoginFilter.UsernameFilterGeneric(boolean)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29772: error 9: Removed public constructor NoCopySpan.Concrete()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29815: error 9: Removed public constructor Spannable.Factory()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:29996: error 9: Removed public constructor TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(char)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30439: error 9: Removed public constructor AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30440: error 9: Removed public constructor AlignmentSpan.Standard(Parcel)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30560: error 9: Removed public constructor LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30561: error 9: Removed public constructor LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30562: error 9: Removed public constructor LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(Parcel)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30724: error 9: Removed public constructor TabStopSpan.Standard(int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30836: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.Builder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30844: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.CardinalBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30845: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.CardinalBuilder(long)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30846: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.CardinalBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30852: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DateBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30853: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DateBuilder(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30861: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DecimalBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30862: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DecimalBuilder(double,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30863: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DecimalBuilder(String,String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30871: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DigitsBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30872: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.DigitsBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30877: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.ElectronicBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30890: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.FractionBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30891: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.FractionBuilder(long,long,long)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30901: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.MeasureBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30915: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.MoneyBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30924: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.OrdinalBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30925: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.OrdinalBuilder(long)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30926: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.OrdinalBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30932: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.SemioticClassBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30940: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.TelephoneBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30941: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.TelephoneBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30948: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.TextBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30949: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.TextBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30954: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.TimeBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30955: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.TimeBuilder(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30961: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.VerbatimBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:30962: error 9: Removed public constructor TtsSpan.VerbatimBuilder(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:31227: error 9: Removed public constructor Transition.EpicenterCallback()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:32173: error 9: Removed public constructor GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:32361: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyCharacterMap.KeyData()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:32369: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyCharacterMap.UnavailableException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:32744: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyEvent.DispatcherState()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33055: error 9: Removed public constructor MotionEvent.PointerCoords()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33056: error 9: Removed public constructor MotionEvent.PointerCoords(PointerCoords)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33073: error 9: Removed public constructor MotionEvent.PointerProperties()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33074: error 9: Removed public constructor MotionEvent.PointerProperties(PointerProperties)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33129: error 9: Removed public constructor ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33174: error 9: Removed public constructor Surface.OutOfResourcesException()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33175: error 9: Removed public constructor Surface.OutOfResourcesException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33199: error 9: Removed public constructor SurfaceHolder.BadSurfaceTypeException()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33200: error 9: Removed public constructor SurfaceHolder.BadSurfaceTypeException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33889: error 9: Removed public constructor View.AccessibilityDelegate()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33902: error 9: Removed public constructor View.BaseSavedState(Parcel)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33903: error 9: Removed public constructor View.BaseSavedState(Parcelable)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33908: error 9: Removed public constructor View.DragShadowBuilder(View)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33909: error 9: Removed public constructor View.DragShadowBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33910: error 9: Removed public method android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder.getView
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:33916: error 9: Removed public constructor View.MeasureSpec()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34209: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34210: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34211: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34223: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34224: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34225: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34226: error 9: Removed public constructor ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34627: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowId.FocusObserver()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34659: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.BadTokenException()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34660: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.BadTokenException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34664: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34665: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34669: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34670: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams(int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34671: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34672: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams(int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34673: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams(int,int,int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34674: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams(int,int,int,int,int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:34675: error 9: Removed public constructor WindowManager.LayoutParams(Parcel)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35045: error 9: Removed public constructor AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction(int,CharSequence)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35218: error 9: Removed public constructor CaptioningManager.CaptioningChangeListener()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35314: error 9: Removed public constructor Animation.Description()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35399: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayoutAnimationController.AnimationParameters()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35438: error 9: Removed public constructor LayoutAnimationController.AnimationParameters()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35584: error 9: Removed public constructor CursorAnchorInfo.Builder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:35859: error 9: Removed public constructor InputMethodSubtype.InputMethodSubtypeBuilder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36173: error 9: Removed public constructor WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36535: error 9: Removed public constructor WebView.WebViewTransport()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36688: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsListView.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36689: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsListView.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36690: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsListView.LayoutParams(int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36691: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36757: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(int,int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36758: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36759: error 9: Removed public constructor AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36781: error 9: Removed public constructor ActionMenuView.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36782: error 9: Removed public constructor ActionMenuView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36783: error 9: Removed public constructor ActionMenuView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36784: error 9: Removed public constructor ActionMenuView.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:36841: error 9: Removed public constructor AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo(View,int,long)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37365: error 9: Removed public constructor ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo(View,long,long)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37401: error 9: Removed public constructor Filter.FilterResults()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37434: error 9: Removed public constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37435: error 9: Removed public constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37436: error 9: Removed public constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37437: error 9: Removed public constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37438: error 9: Removed public constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37439: error 9: Removed public constructor FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37462: error 9: Removed public constructor Gallery.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37463: error 9: Removed public constructor Gallery.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37464: error 9: Removed public constructor Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37515: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayout.LayoutParams(Spec,Spec)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37516: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayout.LayoutParams()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37517: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37518: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayout.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37519: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37520: error 9: Removed public constructor GridLayout.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37712: error 9: Removed public constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37713: error 9: Removed public constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37714: error 9: Removed public constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int,int,float)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37715: error 9: Removed public constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37716: error 9: Removed public constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37717: error 9: Removed public constructor LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37827: error 9: Removed public constructor ListView.FixedViewInfo()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:37871: error 9: Removed public constructor MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38113: error 9: Removed public constructor RadioGroup.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38114: error 9: Removed public constructor RadioGroup.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38115: error 9: Removed public constructor RadioGroup.LayoutParams(int,int,float)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38116: error 9: Removed public constructor RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38117: error 9: Removed public constructor RadioGroup.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38182: error 9: Removed public constructor RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38183: error 9: Removed public constructor RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38184: error 9: Removed public constructor RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38185: error 9: Removed public constructor RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38186: error 9: Removed public constructor RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38254: error 9: Removed public constructor RemoteViews.ActionException(Exception)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38255: error 9: Removed public constructor RemoteViews.ActionException(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38688: error 9: Removed public constructor TableLayout.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38689: error 9: Removed public constructor TableLayout.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38690: error 9: Removed public constructor TableLayout.LayoutParams(int,int,float)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38691: error 9: Removed public constructor TableLayout.LayoutParams()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38692: error 9: Removed public constructor TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38693: error 9: Removed public constructor TableLayout.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38704: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38705: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38706: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams(int,int,float)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38707: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38708: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams(int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38709: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:38710: error 9: Removed public constructor TableRow.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39052: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(Context,AttributeSet)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39053: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39054: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(int,int,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39055: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39056: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39057: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39058: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:39059: error 9: Removed public constructor Toolbar.LayoutParams(LayoutParams)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:40130: error 9: Removed public constructor ObjectInputStream.GetField()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:40190: error 9: Removed public constructor ObjectOutputStream.PutField()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:40858: error 9: Removed public constructor Character.Subset(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:43965: error 9: Removed public constructor Pipe.SinkChannel(SelectorProvider)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:43970: error 9: Removed public constructor Pipe.SourceChannel(SelectorProvider)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44605: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStore.Builder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44614: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(CallbackHandler)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44626: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStore.PasswordProtection(char)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44633: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(PrivateKey,Certificate)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44643: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(SecretKey)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44648: error 9: Removed public constructor KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(Certificate)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:44828: error 9: Removed public constructor Provider.Service(Provider,String,String,String,List,Map)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:45088: error 9: Removed public constructor CertPath.CertPathRep(String,byte)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:45201: error 9: Removed public constructor Certificate.CertificateRep(String,byte)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47037: error 9: Removed public constructor AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47243: error 9: Removed public constructor DateFormat.Field(String,int)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47385: error 9: Removed public constructor Format.Field(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47410: error 9: Removed public constructor MessageFormat.Field(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47470: error 9: Removed public constructor NumberFormat.Field(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47596: error 9: Removed public constructor AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(K,V)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47597: error 9: Removed public constructor AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(Entry)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47604: error 9: Removed public constructor AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry(K,V)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:47605: error 9: Removed public constructor AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry(Entry)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:48471: error 9: Removed public constructor Locale.Builder()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:48702: error 9: Removed public constructor ResourceBundle.Control()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:49836: error 9: Removed public constructor ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:49841: error 9: Removed public constructor ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:49846: error 9: Removed public constructor ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:49851: error 9: Removed public constructor ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:50118: error 9: Removed public constructor AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer.ConditionObject()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:50165: error 9: Removed public constructor AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.ConditionObject()
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:50260: error 9: Removed public constructor ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:50270: error 9: Removed public constructor ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock(ReentrantReadWriteLock)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:50309: error 9: Removed public constructor Attributes.Name(String)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:51639: error 9: Removed public constructor PSource.PSpecified(byte)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:56296: error 9: Removed public constructor SingleClientConnManager.ConnAdapter(PoolEntry,HttpRoute)
prebuilts/sdk/api/22.txt:56300: error 9: Removed public constructor SingleClientConnManager.PoolEntry()

******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously released in
an SDK.  Please fix the errors listed above.
******************************


make: *** [out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-last-timestamp] Error 38

#### make failed to build some targets (03:08 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I tried to give **make update-api**  which gave me make completed successfully message.Here is the last few lines of it

```
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/emma_out/lib/classes-jarjar.jar
Copying: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-v8-renderscript_intermediates/classes.jar
Docs droiddoc: out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check
javadoc: warning - Multiple sources of package comments found for package "android.media.effect"
DroidDoc took 82 sec. to write docs to out/target/common/docs/doc-comment-check
1 warning
Copying current.txt
Copying removed.txt
Copying system-current.txt
Copying system-removed.txt

#### make completed successfully (02:50 (mm:ss)) ####
```

What am i doing wrong here? Can someone help me to identify the issue?

PS:I wanted to build using java 1.8 only :)